# Custom wireshark disector shows value but fieldname is not visible using lua

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I am testing some network packets of my Organisation's product. We already have custom plugins. I am trying to add some some more fields into those existing plugins (like conversion of 2 byte code to a string and assign it to a field)

Thankyou in advance for reading my query.

--edit

Wireshark version : 2.4.5 (organization's plugins dont work on latest wireshark application)

--edit

**Problem statement:**
I am able to add field and show value, but fieldname is not displayed as defined.

I cannot share the entire .lua file but i will try to explain What i did:

1. Below is the image where I have a field `aprint.type`. this is a two byte field. In .lua file, for display purpose it is appended with corresponding description using a custom function `int_to_enum`.
2. I want to add one more proto field `aprint.typetext` which will show the text.
   [image]

**What I did:**

1. Added a protofield `f_apr_msg_type_txt = ProtoField.string("aprint.typetxt","aprint_type_text")` (Tried `f_apr_msg_type_txt = ProtoField.string("aprint.typetxt","aprint_type_text",FT_STRING)` also)
2. Below the code where subtree `aprint.type` is shown, added my required field as `subtree:add(f_apr_msg_type_txt, msg_type_string)` (Below is image of code extract)
   [image]

I am able to see the text but field Name is shown as `Wireshark Lua text (_ws.lua.text)`
[image]

Comment: please don't use screenshots for code.

Comment: @pynexj, I cannot share the .lua file so ad to only share an extract.

Comment: there's already `type: 9 (State alarm)` displayed. what's the purpose of another `State alarm`?

Answer (score 1):

Normally displaying strings based on numeric values is accomplished by a value string lookup, so you'd have something like so:

```
local aprint_type_vals = {
    [1] = "Foo",
    [2] = "Bar",
    [9] = "State alarm"
}

f_apr_msg_type = ProtoField.uint16("aprint.type", "Type", base.DEC, aprint_type_vals)
f_apr_msg_type_txt = ProtoField.string("aprint.typetxt","aprint_type_text", base.ASCII)
```

... then

```
local msg_type = tvb(offset, 2):le_uint()
subtree:add_le(f_apr_msg_type, tvb(offset, 2))

subtree:add(f_apr_msg_type_txt, tvb(offset, 2), (aprint_type_vals[msg_type] or "Unknown"))

--[[
Alternatively:

subtree:add(f_apr_msg_type_txt, tvb(offset, 2)):set_text("aprint_type_text: " .. (aprint_type_vals[msg_type] or "Unknown"))
--]]
```

I'm also not sure why you need the extra field with only the text when the text is already displayed with the existing field, but that's basically how you'd do it.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Christopher, My intention is to extract wireshark data to .csv using tshark. Currently the field aprint.type shows only numeric integer. I wanted to know its corresponding string value too, So thinking that through this method i will know the string value directly.